# Change pixel data of a rectangle in opencv

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

I used the rectangle array below to loop faces detected by Haar Classifier:

```
for( int i = 0; i < (objects ? objects->total : 0 ); i++ )
{
    CvRect* r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );
    cvRectangle( frame, cvPoint( r->x, r->y ), cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),colors[i%1]);

}
```

But I want to change the pixel data of each face detected in the classifier i.e. change the values of pixels of each rectangle in:

```
CvRect* r;
```

I tried:

```
for( int i = 0; i < (objects ? objects->total : 0 ); i++ )
{
 r[i];
for(int j = r->y; j < r->y + r->height; j++)
{
    for(int k = r->x; k < r->x + r->width; k++)
    {   
    frame->imageData[k*3] = 0;    
        frame->imageData[k*3+2] = 0;
     }
     }
     }
```

to keep only G channel of the face but it is saying that the variable 'r' is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < (objects ? objects->total : 0 ); i++ )
{
    CvRect* r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );
    cvRectangle( frame, cvPoint( r->x, r->y ), ... );
}
```

properly initialized temporary local variable `r` is being used, while in this code:

```
CvRect* r;

for( int i = 0; i < (objects ? objects->total : 0 ); i++ )
{
    r[i];
    for(int j = r->y; j < r->y + r->height; j++)
    {
        for(int k = r->x; k < r->x + r->width; k++)
        {   
            frame->imageData[k*3] = 0;    
            frame->imageData[k*3+2] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

uninitialized pointer `r` is treated as an array and even within the nonsense expression making this code invalid.

Try to replace `r[i]` with `r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );`

Answer (score 0):

Use a new image instance as a roi pointer. Example:

```
Mat myimage(500,500,CV_8U,Scalar(255));
imshow("image",myimage); //white image
cvWaitKey();

//Reference matrix
Mat roi_img(myimage(cvRect(25,25,100,100)));

roi_img.setTo(Scalar(0));
imshow("image",myimage); //image has a black rect area.
cvWaitKey();
```